# Pode me ajudar a otimizar essa consulta SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, query, otimização

Eu estou tendo um problema com essa consulta sql. O tempo de retorno dela ta sendo em media 10 segundos e ta usando 100% da cpu. Provavelmente por que ela usa muitas subquery. Porem eu não estou conseguindo otimizar ela. Alguem tem alguma ideia de q caminho posso seguir ?

```
SELECT id_post, midia, texto, tb_usuario.id, tb_usuario.nome, user, avatar, tipo, tb_comm_post.id_categoria, tb_comm_post.data_criacao, tb_comm_categorias.nome, cor1, cor2,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_liked_comunidade WHERE tb_liked_comunidade.id_post = tb_comm_post.id_post AND flag = 1) as n_like,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_liked_comunidade WHERE tb_liked_comunidade.id_post = tb_comm_post.id_post AND flag = -1) as n_dislike,
    (SELECT flag FROM tb_liked_comunidade WHERE tb_liked_comunidade.id_usuario = ? AND tb_liked_comunidade.id_post = tb_comm_post.id_post) as flag,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_comentario_comunidade WHERE tb_comentario_comunidade.id_post = tb_comm_post.id_post) as n_comentarios
    FROM tb_comm_post
    JOIN tb_usuario ON tb_usuario.id = tb_comm_post.id_autor
    JOIN tb_comm_categorias ON tb_comm_post.id_categoria = tb_comm_categorias.id_categoria
    WHERE tb_comm_post.exibir = 1
    ORDER BY tb_comm_post.data_criacao DESC
    LIMIT 5 OFFSET ?
```

Onde ta o ponto de interrogação "?" é que o dado vem na hora da execução da query

Comment: Tenta colocar os dados em uma tabela temporária, logo após vc aplica as  subconsultas.

Comment: Faz join com tb_liked_comunidade no lugar de subselect e trata com iif ou case (pivot) , join com tb_comentario_comunidade também.

Comment: Rode um EXPLAIN e analise o plano de execução identificando os gargalos.

Comment: Tente fazer sem as subqueries e ir readicionando uma a uma para ver qual está pegando. Lembrando que otimização de consulta SQL é um problema NP-completo, então todo servidor SQL acaba "engasgando" com algumas consultas, mesmo que a otimização seja óbvia para um humano, e acaba tendo de fazer as subconsultas como outras consultas no código do lado cliente.

Comment: As respostas até dão ideias de como melhorar, mas outros problemas de lentidão podem ser causados pela modelagem mal planejada, fazendo de qualquer forma muitas coisas podem falhar, nisto aparecem acusações (não que eu esteja elogiando) que mysql é mais lento q outros bancos, quando na verdade muitos problemas são de um planejamento ruim da estrutura. Só estou comentando para complementar, porque vc pode até ter obtido uma "solução" nas respostas, mas tem coisas que não basta um select "eficiente"

Answer (score 1):

O motivo da lentidão é que para cada linha do seu select você está executando 4 selects. Imagine você executar 4 subselect vezes 10mil linhas...

Eu criaria uma procedure, ou incluiria essas etapas na procedure existente:

```
...

DECLARE

a NUMBER;
b NUMBER;
c NUMBER;
d NUMBER;

BEGIN

a:= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_liked_comunidade WHERE tb_liked_comunidade.id_post = tb_comm_post.id_post AND flag = 1) as n_like,
b:= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_liked_comunidade WHERE tb_liked_comunidade.id_post = tb_comm_post.id_post AND flag = -1) as n_dislike,
c:= (SELECT flag FROM tb_liked_comunidade WHERE tb_liked_comunidade.id_usuario = ? AND tb_liked_comunidade.id_post = tb_comm_post.id_post) as flag,
d:= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_comentario_comunidade WHERE tb_comentario_comunidade.id_post = tb_comm_post.id_post) as n_comentarios

SELECT 
a AS n_like,
b AS n_dislike,
c AS flag,
d AS n_comentarios,
id_post, midia, texto, tb_usuario.id, tb_usuario.nome, user, avatar, tipo, 
tb_comm_post.id_categoria, tb_comm_post.data_criacao, tb_comm_categorias.nome, cor1, cor2

FROM tb_comm_post

INNER JOIN tb_usuario 
    ON tb_usuario.id = tb_comm_post.id_autor

INNER JOIN tb_comm_categorias 
    ON tb_comm_post.id_categoria = tb_comm_categorias.id_categoria

WHERE tb_comm_post.exibir = 1

ORDER BY tb_comm_post.data_criacao DESC

LIMIT 5 OFFSET ?

END

...
```

É possível resolver esse problema também com tabela temporário e cruzar informando que 1 é igual a 1 (ON 1=1) para repetir todos os dados de uma tabela com a outra.

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a respota do @alguém.

Quando falamos de otimização precisamos entender o tempo de consulta que cada tabela possui, pois cada tabela existe um certa quantidade de dados reais e podemos medir o quanto ela pode crescer no futuro. Por sua vez não somente uma query bem feita poderá surtir um efeito positivo. A solução da otimização pode ser diferente dependendo do ambiente que você se encontra hoje, pois talvez a criação de novas tabelas relacionais podem surtir um melhor efeito.

Uma boa solução, que já vi em alguns projetos é criar index nas tabelas e usar os indexex no select, acredito que o tempo de consulta será bem mais eficiente.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT CAMPO
FROM TABELA T WITH (INDEX(INDEX_NOMETABELAINDEXADA))
INNER JOIN OUTRA_TABELA OT
WITH (INDEX(OUTRO_INDICE))
ON OT.ID = T.ID
```